# New line in header

Tags: ag-grid

How to add new line to header text?  I tried below solution, but this will just word wrap the text.  What I need to do is to force the new line

```
.ag-header-cell-label {
    text-overflow: clip;
    overflow: visible;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

And in my html, I added

```
[headerHeight]="48"
```

Comment: @mattliu I had to use !important in order to achieve change you might have expected: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-lpt3nr?file=app/app.component.css

Comment: It looks like that example is using ag-grid 16, so it honors the <br> tags that are put in headerName. This no longer works in ag-grid 20+.

Comment: Here is a github issue where they discuss the sanitizing of html in the headers. It looks like they removed this feature in 19.1.1 https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/2866

Answer (score 7):

What i have tried and works Perfect is

```
.ag-header-cell-label .ag-header-cell-text {
   white-space: pre-wrap !important;
}
```

And Header

```
headerName: "Model \n test",
```

> `\n` for new line and `white-space: pre-wrap !important;` to preserve Line Break.

Here is the example https://jsfiddle.net/z63vt14d/

Comment: You can write like AB \n B

Comment: What version of ag-grid is being used in that jsfiddle? I'm having trouble finding the version details.

Comment: V21.1.0 got that from js

Comment: The code at jsfiddle no longer seems to work.

Comment: @Pierre. Have updated jsfiddle link. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

In latest AG grid version you have to use **setFloatingFiltersHeight** property. Example given below or you can follow https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-header/ (Dynamic Header Height Example from link).

You can set this property on grid ready function.

```
onGridReady(params) {
    params.api.setFloatingFiltersHeight(35) // put height as per your need
}
```

Comment: if I have a headerName "AB", and I want "B" to be on a newline, how does using the **setFloatingFiltersHeight** property help to accomplish this?

Comment: Incorrect answer. `setFloatingFiltersHeight` changes height of filter bar below header, not the header itself. You should use the method `setHeaderHeight` instead. It is mentioned in same link above.